# send an image (as numpy array) 'requests.post'

Tags: python, numpy, python-requests

I am bit puzzled with a very simple thing: I am using an online service for image processing and to send my image I'm using

```
var_0 = requests.post(api_url, params=params, headers=headers, data=image_data)
```

where `image_data` should be encode as a binary string. For example, the following example works properly:

```
image_data = open(image_path, "rb").read()
var_0 = requests.post(api_url, params=params, headers=headers, data=image_data)
```

However, in some cases I need to send an image while it is already opened and is in an numpy.array format.

How should I convert my image to be able to send through requests?

Comment: What image formats are accepted by the service?

Comment: It is Microsoft face recognition API. It uses a binary image format: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cognitive-services/emotion/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is stated at the provided link "The supported input image formats includes JPEG, PNG, GIF(the first frame)s, BMP." Thus your data must be in one of those formats. A numpy array is not suitable. It needs to be converted to e.g. a PNG image.

This is most easily done using the `matplotlib.pyplot.imsave()` function. However, the result should be saved to a memory buffer (to be sent to the API), rather than to a file. The way to handle that in Python, is using an `io.BytesIO()` object.

Taken together, a solution to the problem is

```
import io
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.imsave(buf, image_np, format='png')
image_data = buf.getvalue()
var_0 = requests.post(api_url, params=params, headers=headers, data=image_data)
```

where `image_np` is the image as a `numpy` array.

Note also that the line `image_data = buf.getvalue()` is not necessary. Instead the buffer contents can be used directly in the API call.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to use the OpenCV library, maybe it is very useful for some people since when working with images it is very common to work with OpenCV. Here is my solution:

```
import cv2, requests
import numpy as np
numpy_image = cv2.imread("/path/to/image.png")
api_url = "your_api_url"
_ , encoded_image = cv2.imencode('.jpg', numpy_image)
response = requests.post(api_url, data = encoded_image.tobytes()).json()
```